# Laravel counting rows after join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, join

I want to get the count of joined projects by provinces and send it to the view with its name in an array.

here is my code:

```
public function filterByProvince(Request $request)
{

    $province = [];
    foreach ($request->except(['_token']) as $key => $value) {
        $province[$key] = $key;
    }

    $projects = [];
    foreach ($province as $prov){

        $projects[] = DB::table('places')
            ->join('projects', function ($join) use ($prov) {
                $join->on('places.id', '=', 'projects.place_id')
                    ->where('places.province', '=', $prov);
            })->get();

    }


    return view('admin.projects.province', compact(['projects']));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on what you need, would the following suffice?

```
public function filterByProvince(Request $request)
{
    $count = array();
    $province = [];
    foreach ($request->except(['_token']) as $key => $value) {
        $province[$key] = $key;
    }

    $projects = [];
    foreach ($province as $prov){

        $result = DB::table('places')
            ->join('projects', function ($join) use ($prov) {
                $join->on('places.id', '=', 'projects.place_id')
                    ->where('places.province', '=', $prov);
            })->get();
        $projects[] = $result;
        $count[$prov] = count($result);

    }


    return view('admin.projects.province', compact(['projects', 'count']));

}
```

Comment: Please, if a question is not clear, comment, don't answer. If you can't comment, wait until you have the rep or until someone else comments & the question is clarified.